# NopCommerce- Autofac.Configuration.dll does not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce3.10.

I am trying to create a plugin with data access based on this Tutorial : [Plugin with data access](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/75/plugin-with-data-access.aspx)

When I tried to include references in my plugin, All references included correctly. But when i tried to include `Autofac.Configuration` reference in my plugin, `Autofac.Configuration.dll` does not found at `..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Autofac.Configuration.dll` location.

So how can i include `Autofac.Configuration` reference in my plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Autofac v3.0 the Autofac.Configuration.dll was part of the standard distribution. In subsequent versions, it was moved into its own Nuget package. It sounds like your Autofac Nuget package was upgraded. If so, you need to add the now additional Autofac.Configuration Nuget package to your project.